# Dynamic ad hoc polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, overloading

In my C++ code, I have a collection of classes `A1, A2, ...,` all derived from a class `A`. I also have a vector `v<*A>` holding pointers to objects all of type `A`. I want to implement a function `foo(A *x, A *y)` that is dynamically ad hoc polymorphic in the type of `x` and `y`. To make this more concrete, imagine `A` is `Shape`, `A1, A2, ...,` are `Circle, Rect, ...,` and `foo` is `intersects(Shape *x, Shape *y)`.

I could overload `foo` with declarations like `foo(A1 *x, A2 *y)` for the combinations of derived types of A that I care about, however this will not work for the objects referenced by my vector `v` since function overloading, unlike virtual methods, is handled statically. I also cannot use virtual methods of the form `A1::foo(A2 *y)` since this only dynamically resolves the type of the method's class (`A1`) and not the type of the argument (`A2`).

The only solution I've thought of is to implement `foo` as follows:

```
void foo(A *x, A*y) {
  if (A1* a1 = dynamic_cast<A1*>(x)) {
    if (A1* a1 = dynamic_cast<A1*>(y)) {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
  if (A2* a2 = dynamic_cast<A2*>(x)) {
    if (A1* a1 = dynamic_cast<A1*>(y)) {
      ...
    }  
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

However, I've always been told that resorting to dynamic casts is rarely a good idea. Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve this?

Comment: I concur with what you've been told.  Using dynamic_cast is a very bad code smell.

Comment: Yes, it's called a "visitor pattern". A good C++ textbook will have a full explanation and examples.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I know what a visitor pattern is, but fail to see how it can be applied to this scenario. Could you elaborate?

Comment: This type of dynamic dispatch, between two interacting objects, is called double dispatch. Its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C++) has an example on how to accomplish it in C++ using the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is double dispatch. The visitor pattern can accomplish this. You need a virtual function which makes the first type concrete to apply a visitor. And then you need another virtual function to make the second type concrete and return a visitor:

```
struct Shape
{
    // Each derived class simply calls visit with the concrete type:
    //     return visitor.visit(*this);
    virtual bool accept(const IntersectionVisitor& visitor) const = 0;

    // Each derived class return a visitor which knows how to calculate
    // the intersection of this particular class type with all types of
    // shapes. The visit() overrides of this visitor have access to both
    // concrete shape types.
    virtual IntersectionVisitor intersection_visitor() const = 0;
};

struct IntersectionVisitor
{
    // Calculate the intersection of this concrete shape with a Circle
    virtual bool visit(const Circle&) = 0;

    // Calculate the intersection of this concrete shape with a Rect
    virtual bool visit(const Rect&) = 0;
};

bool intersects(const Shape& shape1, const Shape& shape2)
{
    return shape2.accept(shape1.intersection_visitor());
}
```

Just because you can doesn't mean you should. You can do this more simply with variants:

```
using Shape = std::variant<Circle, Rect, ...>;

bool intersects(const Circle&, const Circle&) { ... }
bool intersects(const Circle&, const Rect&) { ... }
// all shape combinations, like before

// Visitation is just std::visit:
bool intersects(const Shape& shape1, const Shape& shape2)
{
    return std::visit([](const auto& s1, const auto& s2) {
            return intersects(s1, s2);
        }, shape1, shape2);
}
```